# What is AffineTransform?

Tags: java, affinetransform

I'm reading "Beginning Java Game Programming 2/e" and the book heavily emphasizes using AffineTransform.

There is just one problem, it doesn't explain at all what it is, what it does, and the purpose of AffineTransform.

I have done some google searches, but they're just showing me matrix math... Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because an affine transform *is* matrix math. It's any kind of mapping from one image to another that you can construct by moving, scaling, rotating, reflecting, and/or shearing the image. The Java `AffineTransform` class lets you specify these kinds of transformations, then use them to produce modified versions of images.

Comment: could you provide additional information, such as a website that has an indepth explanation?

Comment: I just looked at the Javadoc for the class, it seems pretty good to me, actually, given that you don't want to see much math: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer is years late, but if anyone else is struggling with this then I recommend reading Introduction to 3D Game Programming With DirectX 11 by Frank Luna. It is a very good book. Though book is about DirectX 11 the first three chapters are just about the math concepts needed for graphics. The chapters explains the math well and provided lots of exercises to practice the topics at the end of the chapter. (You may doing 2D games but the math is the same, the vectors and matrices have just one less dimension.)